# How to show only one element of a page using css

Tags: css

I have a web page, for example one showing a Google Analytics report. One of the graphs is in a div with id = "ID-overview-graph". How can I use css to show only it in the page?

I've tried:

```
body {
  display: none
}

#ID-overview-graph {
  display: block
}
```

which didn't work for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all other elements on the page are `div` elements, you could do:

```
div:not(#ID-overview-graph) {
    display: none;
}
```

This way, you're not using such an expensive selector as the wildcard selector `*`

If you have other elements, you could list them all out with that `:not()` statement.

If you can include the rest of your html, that would be helpful.